# Python-docx: Is it possible to add a new run to paragraph in a specific place (not at the end)

Tags: python, python-docx

I want to set a style to a corrected word in MS Word text.
Since it's not possible to change text style inside a run, I want to insert a new run with new style into the existing paragraph...

```
for p in document.paragraphs: 
   for run in p.runs: 
       if 'text' in run.text:      
            new_run= Run()
            new_run.text='some new text' 
            # insert this run into paragraph
            # smth like:
            p.insert(new_run)
```

**How to do it?**

`p.add_run()` adds run to the end of paragraph, doesn't it?

### Update

The best would be to be able to clone run (and insert it after a certain run). This way we reproduce the original run's style attributes in the new/cloned one.

### Update 2

I could manage that insertion code:

```
if 'text' in run.text:
    new_run_element = CT_R() #._new() 
    run._element.addnext(new_run_element)
    new_run = Run(new_run_element, run._parent)
    ...
```

But after that:

1. the **paragraph runs number is left the same**: `len(p.runs)`
2. as I save that doc in file, the **MS Word fails to open it**:
   [image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no API support for this, but it can be readily accomplished at the oxml/lxml level:

```
from docx.text.run import Run
from docx.oxml.text.run import CT_R
# ...
for run in p.runs:
    if 'text' in run.text:
        new_run_element = p._element._new_r()
        run._element.addnext(new_run_element)
        new_run = Run(new_run_element, run._parent)
        # ---do things with new_run, e.g.---
        new_run.text = 'Foobar'
        new_run.bold = True
```

If you want to insert the new run prior to the existing run, use `run._element.addprevious(new_run_element)`. These two are methods on the `lxml.etree._Element` class which all `python-docx` elements subclass.
https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html

Comment: I've followed your code, but why when I run `r = CT_R.new()` I get the following error:

`r = CT_R.new()

AttributeError: type object 'CT_R' has no attribute 'new'` ?

Comment: both in [CT_R class](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/oxml/text/run.py) and [Run class](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/text/run.py) I've not found any methods that you've using in that code...
Also, see the **question Update**.

Comment: please see **Update and Update 2**.

Comment: Okay, apologies, I probably shouldn't try to do this from memory. There are a few approaches that can work you can replace that line with: `new_run_element = p._element._new_r()` and that should work. I'll update the code snippet.

Comment: thanks, it works. Where can I find docs on `._element._new_r()`, `._element.addnext()` methods and similar?

Comment: `_Element.addnext()` is an `lxml` method you can find at the link at the bottom of the answer. `._new_r()` is a method added to the `CT_P` class by the metaclass underlying `BaseOxmlElement` (in `docx.oxml.xmlchemy` roughly [here](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/oxml/xmlchemy.py#L286) as a result of the `r = ZeroOrMore('w:r')` child element declaration in `CT_P` [here](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/oxml/text/paragraph.py#L16). This metaclass is how custom element classes are created customized to the particular element.

Comment: If you replace `p._element._new_r()` with `deepcopy(run.element)` you preserve the style of the previous run instead of clearing it.