# Create footer in word docx by creating a footer.xml file in the word - folder of the docx.zip via python?

Tags: python-docx

No idea how I can do this considering the (randomly?) generated rsids in the xml code, anyone has a solution?

```
from docx.text.run import Run
from docx import Document

doc = Document('/Users/cezi/Desktop/ME.docx')

p = doc.sections[0].footer.paragraphs[0]

for run in p.runs:
    if ' ' in run.text:
        new_run_element = p._element._new_r()
        run._element.addprevious(new_run_element)
        new_run = Run(new_run_element, run._parent)
        new_run.text = "left"
        new_run.add_tab()
        new_run.add_text("Page")

p.add_run().add_tab()
p.add_run("right")

doc.save("HOW.docx")
```

Comment: Say why you want to do it, what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to be able to do it to automate the generation of the following in the footer of a word docx generated via python-docx:

"Page" + Page # + "/" + Total Amount of Pages

in another way than via a template. I want to be able to do that cause it's the only part of my word docx I can't generate with my python docx code, it's the last missing part. Given that you can't access or define word fields with python docx, the only solution I saw is by adding the user specified footer via a created xml footer file.

Comment: Another solution would be if I would access the paragraph of the corresponding footer of the template, which would be only 

<Page # + "/" + Total Amount of Pages>

and then add a run in front of this part, being the word "Pages", in function of the user-specified language. But I have no clue how to place a run before the first run of a paragraph via python docx. You know how to do that maybe?

Comment: The best would be: access the <Page # + "/" + Total Amount of Pages > part of the footer, which is centered. Then, previous to that run, add one run which is left justified, then add one run which is placed right before the <Page # + "/" + Total Amount of Pages> part, and then one run which is right justified (this last one probably simply add with .add_run() after adding some tabs). If you may have any idea for that? Concerning the code, I can easily access the run containing the <Page #> element, but from upon there I'm lost.

Comment: actually one of your previous posts allowed me to do the attempt by adding runs previously to the word fields scanny (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740630/python-docx-is-it-possible-to-add-a-new-run-to-paragraph-in-a-specific-place-n) cheers! code inserted above for interested people, try it out on a template word with simply " " + <Page #> + "/" + <Total Page #> written in your footer. Anyway, would still be interested in generating the whole word doc, including the page word fields, with docx, without the use of any template docx.